# The limits of the use of accents package

Tags: packages, accents, compilation-error

We suppose to have this minimal compilable code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
$\accentset{\overset{\overset{\sim}{\square}}{c}}{\bm{\mathrm{x}}}(t)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Inside the first curly bracket `\overset{\overset{\sim}{\square}}{c}` of the command `\accentset` I can put a castle of symbols.

> Why this package give me several errors when I use `\tilde` or `\dot`?

> What characters should be deleted?

**MWE that it does not compile**:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
$\accentset{\overset{\overset{\tilde}{\dot}}{\sim}}{\bm{\mathrm{x}}}(t)$
\end{document}
```

The file `.log` it is very long.

Comment: I'd say the short answer is that `\tilde` and `\dot` are not symbols, but macros which take an argument. That's doomed.

Comment: @campa Very kind campa. I didn't know about this. Hence these fake symbols not can never be used or is there a shortcut or a trick?

Comment: As \tilde and \dot are already accents, I think the syntax should be `$ \tilde{\dot{\accentset{\sim}{\mathbf{x}}}} $` (as I don't see any difference between `\bm{\mathrm{…}}` and `\mathbf{…}`, I replaced it with latter.

Comment: @Bernard Very kind Bernard yes, you're right. I have seen that the manual that it is equal to your comment. +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't clear what the intention of `\overset` is here. There are two accent mechanisms involved, commands that are defined as accents, that take an argument, like `\tilde`. Then commands constructed with `\accentset` that can be used with a symbol to fake an accent taking the symbol and placing it over the base. So to stack `\tilde`, `dot` and `\sim` you just need

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
$\tilde{\dot{\accentset{\sim}{\bm{\mathrm{x}}}}}(t)$
\end{document}
```

Although `\bm{\mathrm{x}}` could more easily (and efficiently) be written as `\mathbf{x}`

Comment: Great David. Of course for the \mathbf{x}. I am lazy at this period with my mind :-((((. Hence always the \tilde must be to external? I.e. I must to start to \tilde{.....} to have not the mistakes?

Comment: @Sebastiano I don't understand your question, you only need to start with tilde if that is the top accent. they just get stacked in the order you give

Answer (score 2):

You can overcome the compilation errors by using the `\mathchar`s associated with `\tilde` and `\dot`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
$\accentset{\overset{\overset{\mathchar"307E}{\mathchar"05F}}{\sim}}{\bm{\mathrm{x}}}(t)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, given the poor spacing and sizing, one might consider a stack alternative:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\stackMath
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
$\setstackgap{S}{-5pt}
\stackon[-1pt]{\bm{\mathrm{x}}}
  {\Shortstack{\mathchar"307E\\\mathchar"05F\\\scriptscriptstyle\sim}}(t)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the new answer. My best regards and thankkkkkkkkkk youuuuu.